# Pivot with dates of given month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a view I'm trying to process and present in a more usable way using SQL Server.

The data:

```
select * 
from vReportData 
where date between '01.01.2020' and '31.01.2020'
```

which looks like this:

```
  persnr    date          abw     target  attendance
 ----------------------------------------------------
  000001    2020-01-01            5.00    4.45
  000001    2020-01-02            0.00    8.00
  000001    2020-01-04            6.00    7.00
  000001    2020-01-30            6.00    6.00
  000001    2020-01-31            6.00    6.50
  [...]
  999999    2020-01-02    U       5.00    0.00
  999999    2020-01-30            4.00    5.00
  999999    2020-01-31            5.00    5.00
```

The desired output:

```
persnr    01.01.2020  02.01.2020  [...]   30.01.2020  31.01.2020   sum
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
000001    4.45/5.00   8.00/0.00   [...]   6.00/6.00   6.50/6.00    xxx
999999                U           [...]   5.00/4.00   0.00/5.00    xxx
```

Basically I would like to transform the table to have one line per person and have the dates as column. As for the abw, target and attendance I want to get them to be displayed by the date it happened.

**The idea**

I'm very likely need to use pivot function to get the table shape I want. Since I don't have all dates of a given month in my `vReportData` I thought about generating them first using something along the lines of:

```
declare @start datetime = '2020-05-01'
declare @ende datetime = '2020-05-31'

;with calender AS 
(
    select @start as Datum
    union all
    select Datum + 1 from Calender
    where Datum + 1 <= @ende
)
select [Date] = convert(varchar, Datum, 104), 0.00 as value 
from calender
```

to get the dates of the given month as rows.

Adding the persnr I ended up with:

```
select distinct 
    #vReportData.persnr, 
    [Date] = convert(varchar, Datum, 104) 
from  
    calender 
cross join 
    #vReportData
```

I don't how how to get the pivot working using my approach.

My complete SQL + attempt can be found here - for testing purpose I ended up changing the end date at some point.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1240742/reportdata

## additon & followup:

I was trying a few other attemts. Here's another issue I encountered:

I ended up using a dynamic pivot where I was first selecting the dates and then adding them to the pivot. I have the desired table form, but not one line per persnr.

```
declare @dynQuery as nvarchar(MAX)
declare @cols as nvarchar(MAX)

select @cols= isnull(@cols + ',','') 
       + quotename(convert(varchar, date, 104))
from (select distinct date from app_hours
where date between '01.01.2020' and '31.01.2020'
) AS Dates

SET @dynQuery = 
  N'select distinct persnr, ' + @cols + '
    from app_hours
    pivot (
        sum(attendancetime)

          for date in (' + @cols + ')) 

          AS pivot where persnr = 000001'

EXEC sp_executesql @dynQuery
```

the table looks like this:

```
persnr      01.01.2020      02.01.2020     03.01.2020   [...]
----------------------------------------------------------------
000001      NULL            NULL           5.00          ...
000001      NULL            5.00           NULL          ...
000001      5.00            NULL           NULL          ...
```

Comment: What's the sum column in your desired output?

Comment: Will the result always contain 31 or less dates, or could there be more dates in the result set?

Comment: @RossBush well, between 28-31 depending on the given month, but never less. if there are no data, the value can be `NULL`

Comment: @acutemattiosis the sum of attendancetime

Comment: So, [sum] should just display the sum of all attendance for a single person.

Taking your desired result set: where [persnr] = 1, [sum] = 24.95 and where [persnr] = 999999, [sum] = 10.00. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the pain with pivots is having to name all the columns in your build statement, especially when that list is big or prone to change -- which, as you've pointed out, is best done with dynamic SQL.

I've used the EOMONTH function, a recursive CTE and a temp table to populate the list of pivot columns. Then used dynamic SQL to build and execute the PIVOT.

I need a little more clarity around what the [sum] column is actually adding, and your expected output for your example data set, before I can incorporate that.

But without the [sum] column...

```
-- declare vars
DECLARE @columns_select AS VARCHAR(MAX), @columns_pivot AS VARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @start_date AS DATE, @end_date AS DATE ;
DECLARE @sqlCmd AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

-- determine start date
SET @start_date = ( SELECT TOP(1) DATEADD ( DD, 1, EOMONTH ( [date], -1 ) )
                    FROM #vReportData ORDER BY [date] ASC ) ;
-- determine end date
SET @end_date   = ( SELECT TOP(1) EOMONTH ( [date], 0 )
                    FROM #vReportData ORDER BY [date] DESC ) ;

-- generate date range to temp table
WITH cte_DateCols1 AS
(
    SELECT  @start_date AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD ( DD, 1, [date] )
    FROM    cte_DateCols1
    WHERE   [date] < @end_date
)
SELECT  [date]
INTO    #tbl_Dates
FROM    cte_DateCols1 ;

-- populate list of columns for SELECT statement
SELECT  @columns_select = CONCAT ( @columns_select, ', ISNULL ( ', QUOTENAME ( [date] ), ', '''' ) AS '
                            , QUOTENAME ( CONVERT ( VARCHAR(10), [date], 104 ) ) )
FROM    #tbl_Dates ;

-- populate list of columns for PIVOT statement
SELECT  @columns_pivot = CONCAT ( @columns_pivot, ', ', QUOTENAME ( [date] ) )
FROM    #tbl_Dates ;
SET     @columns_pivot = RIGHT ( @columns_pivot, LEN ( @columns_pivot ) - 2 ) ;

-- drop temp table
DROP TABLE #tbl_Dates ;

-- build dynamic SQL PIVOT statement
SET @sqlCmd = N'
WITH cte_Data AS
(
    SELECT      [persnr]
                , CAST ( [date] AS DATE ) AS [date]
                , CASE [abw] 
                    WHEN ''U'' THEN ''U''
                    WHEN '''' THEN CONCAT ( [attendance], ''/'', [target] ) 
                    ELSE NULL
                END AS [result]
    FROM        #vReportData
)
SELECT      RIGHT ( ''00000'' + CAST ( [persnr] AS VARCHAR(6) ), 6 ) AS [persnr]
            ' + @columns_select + '
FROM        cte_Data
PIVOT       (           
                MAX ( [result] )
                FOR [date]
                IN  ( ' + @columns_pivot + ' )
            ) AS pvt 
ORDER BY    [persnr] ASC ;' ;

-- execute dynamic SQL PIVOT statement
PRINT @sqlCmd ;
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sqlCmd ;
GO
```

**Updated for Attendance Totals**

You should be able to grab the [attendance] totals using a SUM function on the CTE output, before applying the pivot, and tack it onto the end of your pivot output, like this...

```sql
-- declare vars
DECLARE @columns_select AS VARCHAR(MAX), @columns_pivot AS VARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @start_date AS DATE, @end_date AS DATE ;
DECLARE @sqlCmd AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

-- determine start date
SET @start_date = ( SELECT TOP(1) DATEADD ( DD, 1, EOMONTH ( [date], -1 ) )
                    FROM #vReportData ORDER BY [date] ASC ) ;
-- determine end date
SET @end_date   = ( SELECT TOP(1) EOMONTH ( [date], 0 )
                    FROM #vReportData ORDER BY [date] DESC ) ;

-- generate date range to temp table
WITH cte_DateCols AS
(
    SELECT  @start_date AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD ( DD, 1, [date] )
    FROM    cte_DateCols
    WHERE   [date] < @end_date
)
SELECT  [date]
INTO    #tbl_Dates
FROM    cte_DateCols ;

-- populate list of columns for SELECT statement
SELECT  @columns_select = CONCAT ( @columns_select, ', ISNULL ( ', QUOTENAME ( [date] ), ', '''' ) AS '
                            , QUOTENAME ( CONVERT ( VARCHAR(10), [date], 104 ) ) )
FROM    #tbl_Dates ;

-- populate list of columns for PIVOT statement
SELECT  @columns_pivot = CONCAT ( @columns_pivot, ', ', QUOTENAME ( [date] ) )
FROM    #tbl_Dates ;
SET     @columns_pivot = RIGHT ( @columns_pivot, LEN ( @columns_pivot ) - 2 ) ;

-- drop temp table
DROP TABLE #tbl_Dates ;

-- build dynamic SQL PIVOT statement
SET @sqlCmd = N'
WITH cte_Data AS
(
    SELECT      [persnr]
                , CAST ( [date] AS DATE ) AS [date]
                , CASE [abw] 
                    WHEN ''U'' THEN ''U''
                    WHEN '''' THEN CONCAT ( [attendance], ''/'', [target] ) 
                    ELSE NULL
                END AS [result]
    FROM        #vReportData
)
, cte_DataWithTotals AS
(
    SELECT      r.[persnr]
                , SUM ( CAST ( r.[attendance] AS DECIMAL (5,2) ) ) AS [total_attendance]
                , d.[date]
                , d.[result]
    FROM        #vReportData AS r
    INNER JOIN  cte_Data AS d
        ON      r.[persnr] = d.[persnr]
    GROUP BY    r.[persnr], d.[date], d.[result]
)
SELECT      RIGHT ( ''00000'' + CAST ( [persnr] AS VARCHAR(6) ), 6 ) AS [persnr]
            ' + @columns_select + '
            , [total_attendance] AS [attendance_sum]
FROM        cte_DataWithTotals
PIVOT       (           
                MAX ( [result] )
                FOR [date]
                IN  ( ' + @columns_pivot + ' )
            ) AS pvt 
ORDER BY    [persnr] ASC ;' ;

-- execute dynamic SQL PIVOT statement
PRINT @sqlCmd ;
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sqlCmd ;
GO
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. quite annoying feature of pivot, but I guess it has it's reason. I just tried to add another column at the end (sum - to sum all attendance) but I failed miserable.

Comment: hi @acutemattiosis I took a closer look at the script. It does work, but apparently it causes issues when you have a lot more data.

Comment: When you say is doesn't work, are you getting any errors or is the result set incorrect?

And when you say a lot more data, do you mean many, many more rows or a wider date range?Are the results in your sample set representative of all possible combinations of data (especially with regards to the [abw] column)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to add a floating subtotal placeholder to be offset from the last column of real data. This does not solve the column headers problem that was solved above, however, you could either create a SP to produce your headers laid out similarly or convert the pivot part to dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @vReportData TABLE (
  [persnr] int, 
  [date] datetime, 
  [abw] varchar(5), 
  [target] float, 
  [attendance] float
);

INSERT INTO @vReportData
    ([persnr], [date], [abw], [target], [attendance])
VALUES
    (000001, '2020-01-01', '', 5.00, 4.45),
    (000001, '2020-01-02', '', 0.00, 8.00),
    (000001, '2020-01-04', '', 6.00, 7.00),
    (000001, '2020-01-30', '', 6.00, 6.00),
    (000001, '2020-01-31', '', 6.00, 6.50),

    (999999, '2020-01-02', 'U', 6.00, 0.00),
    (999999, '2020-01-30', '', 4.00, 5.00),
    (999999, '2020-01-31', '', 5.00, 5.00)

declare @start datetime = '2020-01-01'
declare @ende datetime = '2020-01-04'

DECLARE @SubtotalPosition INT = DATEDIFF(DAY, @start,@ende) + 2

;with calender AS 
(
    select @start as Datum
    union all
    select Datum + 1 from Calender
    where Datum + 1 <= @ende
)
,DistinctUsers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT persnr FROM @vReportData
) 
,MakeSubTotalPlaceholders AS
(
    --Add placeholder to place at the end of the real data as subtotal buckets
    select IsPlaceHolder=1, persnr, date = @ende, abw=null, target=0, attendance=null FROM DistinctUsers

    UNION ALL

    SELECT IsPlaceHolder=0, v.persnr, date, abw, target, attendance FROM  @vReportData v
    WHERE
        v.date BETWEEN @start AND @ende
)
,ReadyForPivotWithTotal AS
(
    SELECT
        persnr, date, abw, target, attendance,
        DayOffset = CASE WHEN IsPlaceHolder = 1 THEN @SubtotalPosition  ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY,date)) END,
        total = CASE WHEN IsPlaceHolder = 1  THEN SUM(target) OVER (PARTITION BY persnr) ELSE target END
    FROM
        MakeSubTotalPlaceholders
)
SELECT persnr,
    P1=MAX([1]),P2=MAX([2]),P3=MAX([3]),P4=MAX([4]),P5=MAX([5]),P6=MAX([6]),P7=MAX([7]),P8=MAX([8]),P9=MAX([9]),P10=MAX([10]),P11=MAX([11]),P12=MAX([12]),
    P13=MAX([13]),P14=MAX([14]),P15=MAX([15]),P16=MAX([16]),P17=MAX([17]),P18=MAX([18]),P19=MAX([19]),P20=MAX([20]),P21=MAX([21]),P22=MAX([22]),P23=MAX([23]),P24=MAX([24]),
    P25=MAX([25]),P26=MAX([26]),P27=MAX([27]),P28=MAX([28]),P29=MAX([29]),P30=MAX([30]),P31=MAX([31]),P32=MAX([32])
FROM 
    ReadyForPivotWithTotal A

PIVOT
(
    MAX(total)
    FOR DayOffSet IN 
    (
        [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],
        [13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],
        [25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32]
    )
)AS B   
GROUP BY 
    persnr
```